# AbstractBaseUser - creating a model leads to Field 'id' expected a number but got string?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a custom `User` model:

When I hit the end-point to register a user I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1988, in get_prep_value
> return int(value)

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hashtag'

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/Volumes/coding/user_django/accounts/api.py", line 25, in post
> serializer.save()
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
> self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
> File "/Volumes/coding/user_django/accounts/serializers.py", line 38, in create
> user = User.objects.create_user(username=validated_data['username'],
> File "/Volumes/coding/user_django/accounts/models.py", line 18, in create_user
> user.save()
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 68, in save
> super().save(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
> self.save_base(
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 857, in save_base
> updated = self._save_table(
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 970, in _save_table
> updated = self._do_update(
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1013, in _do_update
> filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1071, in filter
> return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
> clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
> self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1502, in add_q
> clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in _add_q
> child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1448, in build_filter
> condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1273, in build_lookup
> lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 27, in **init**
> self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 85, in get_prep_lookup
> return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
> File "/Users/xxx/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1990, in get_prep_value
> raise e.**class**(
> ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'test123'.

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Please fill a username')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Please fill in an Email')
        print("We passed UserManager checks")
        user = self.model(username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        print("we are just before user save in create_user, DONE")

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password is needed')
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Please fill a username')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Please fill in an Email')

        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user = self.model(username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # id = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    # Change the username default field to email
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # username
    # Fields that are required
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def tokens(self):
        return ''
```

> api.py

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        print(serializer.validated_data)
        serializer.save()
        print('validated_data')
        user_data = serializer.validated_data
        # print('validated_data')
        print(user_data)
        return Response(user_data)
```

> serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6,
                                     write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
        # extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        username = attrs.get('username', '')
        if not username.isalnum():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username can only contain alpha-numeric characters")
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('Increate')
        # validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=validated_data['username'],
                                        email=validated_data['email'],
                                        password=validated_data['password'])
        print("Passed user create")
        return user
```

> 0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.6 on 2022-09-30 12:35

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)),
                ('is_verified', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('created_at', models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateField(auto_now=True)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

The `id` in migrations is an `auto_created`, am I somehow overiding the `auto_created` and giving the `username` field for `id`?

I can't spot the error.

I initially tried swapping this code into the `accounts` app of existing project. Thought that might be the issue so started a fresh project and I get the same error. Tried multiple answers to this question such as running `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate`, deleteing the migrations files and doing migrate again. Dropping the db. Nothing is working.

Using postman:

```
Post request to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register/
Body:
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "username": "test123",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Comment: Found the error leaving this here for anyone else who might have a similar error:

`user = self.model(username, email=self.normalize_email(email))` in `models.py` was overwriting `id` as that is the expected first argument. I changed it to: `user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))` and it works. I got another error: >AssertionError: `create()` did not return an object instance. I was not using a return user at the end of `create_user` in `models.py`